# Understanding All Subscriber behaviour in Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud, list

**Setup** 
In our SFMC instance we have a parent BU and two child BU's mapped to it. I also have data extensions within the child BU's that contain Contact records from our integrated salesforce CRM instance.

**Behaviour** 
Whenever I send an email through email studio or journey builder from one of the child BU's, the contact get's added to the *All Subscriber* view in the Parent BU and is not available in the *All Subscriber* view in the child BU. The contact could be a new contact or an existing one but it always shows up in the parent BU.

**Question** 
Is it possible to have these contacts added within the specific child BU from where they have been sent an email from? It's ok if they are added in the Parent BU as well but we need our BU specific users to be able to view them in "All Subscribers".

If this is not supported then will I need to create a new BU specific list and have all contacts published to that list to achieve this view? This seems to be a fairly common use case and I wanted to understand how to best address this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you have Business Unit Filters configured.

When you send an email to a data extension, the contacts will always be added to All Subscribers at the parent level. These subscribers are shared across the enterprise, however you can hide/filter subscribers so only specific subscribers appear at the child business unit level. This is done using 'Business Unit Subscriber Filters'.

Go to Administration > Business Units
Select the child business unit, and you should see the button "Define Subscriber Filter"

When you configure a filter on the business unit, only the subscribers who match the rule will appear in All Subscribers of the child business unit - but they will always live on the parent business unit

Comment: This was the issue, after removing the subscriber filter I am able to see All Subscribers in all BU's. But this leads to another issue. I don't need BU users to actually view and use subscribers from the other BU. Is there a way to prevent this access ? I understand subscriber filters can only really use the subscriber attributes which are not really comprehensive for our use case.

Comment: If you don't want users to view or use All Subscribers, then you can remove the permission in their role. Within Roles, it's permissions are under Email > Subscribers > All Subscribers. You might also wish to manage the permissions for Contact Builder too

Answer (score 6):

All Subscribers list is common across all BUs (parent and child).

When you send email to set of users in say child BU1, all subscribers list will be populated with these users in all BUs including the parent BU.  This is by default.  If any discrepancy, raise a support ticket.

**Status of All Subscribers**

- The Active/UnSubscribed status of these users in All Subscribers list will be different across BUs and is also dependant on unsubscribe settings of the Business Unit.
- When the business unit is set as ‘Unsubscribe from this Business Unit
  Only’, the Active/UnSubscribed status of All Subscribers is maintained separately across
  BUs.
- The bounced/held status will be the same across all BUs in All
  Subscribers list irrespective of the settings.